# How to lock another app from using in Android Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to lock apps for a short time period in Android using Flutter. I searched in the internet and didn't find a solution. I want to lock apps like in digital wellbeing. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Lock the app you are currently running or others app on device ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh other apps on device.

Comment: LOL Are you trying to write a ransomware app? This idea would be a big security issue. If you control the apps you want to lock down, then you have options. Otherwise, please don't write an app that locks other apps that don't belong to you. That's a crappy thing to do. If you need to lock down employee phones, there are management tools for that. They exist for home users, but aren't usually cost effective for home use. Or you can build your own Android installation from ASOP with your logic built into the OS and ask users to install that. Or use iPhone and Guided Access.

Comment: @daddygames I'm trying to create a productivity app. The user controls which apps he want lock

Comment: Without more details about your project, it's hard to see a use case where locking down apps that don't belong to you is okay.

Comment: @daddygames If some video game is a distraction the user will be able to lock down the app for a limited time like in digital wellbeing in android.

Comment: From what I can tell Digital Wellbeing is more like iOS 15's new Focus feature that hides app notifications so they aren't distracting. It doesn't lock apps down from my understanding of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237935/discussion-between-lovinduli-and-daddygames).